# redirect stubbed in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to redirect to a component on button click, Here is what I have done :

```
import { Redirect, Router } from "react-router-dom";
class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    buttonState: ""
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buttonOnClick = this.buttonOnClick.bind(this);
  }

  buttonOnClick(e) {
    this.setState({ buttonState: e.target.id }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.buttonState);
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      let url = "/" + this.state.redirect;
      console.log(url);
      return (
        <Router>
          <Redirect to={url} />
        </Router>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <button id={"users"} onClick={this.buttonOnClick}>
            See all users
          </button>
          <button id={"others"} onClick={this.buttonOnClick}>
            other
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Here it console.log perfectly, but it doesn't redirect.

**How this can be resolved?**

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/redirect-test-fuwvn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Router>
          <Redirect to={url} />
        </Router>
```

This will work, see my [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/redirect-test-fuwvn)

Answer (score 2):

Ok if you want to redirect to a path that is located in your project you can do that by using this code :

```js
onClick = () => 
    this.props.history.push('your route');
```

and if you want to redirect user to a path that is not located in your project use this code :

```js
onClick = () => 
    windows.location.href = 'your route'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I have found out that you did not declare `redirect` under your `state` variable, the only variable in it is the `buttonState`.

However, I would like to suggest an another way to redirect.

You could wrap each button on a `Link` tag. It would be

```
<Link to="/your_route_here">
   <button ...> 
   </button>
</Link>
```

You can also refer to the official doc of `react-router-dom` for `Link` tag [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link).

Comment: i can you link, i want to use redirect specifically